# Aurelia mechanism for dynamically loading HTML View templates

Tags: requirejs, amd, aurelia, requirejs-text, almond

I realize from the [Aurelia 0.10.0 Release & Status](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/03/25/aurelia-0-10-0-release-status/) blog post that Aurelia's "bundling solution is about 50% complete".

For the purpose of releasing a standalone embeddable Aurelia app (on 3rd party site), am interested to know if there is currently a method for loading HTML view templates dynamically for use with [RequireJS (Almond)](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) and the text! plugin or an equivalent (SystemJS or other) mechanism.

Or do we need to wait for the bundler?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to do this currently. However, that's something we can add...and we do expect to make some improvements in this area as part of our general bundling work.

Comment: To expound on what Rob said: Currently, the Default Loader for Aurelia uses SystemJS to get the path to a template. After that, HTMLTemplate technology is used to actually load the template.

That being said, if you feel up to it, you could take the Default Loader code and change it to use SystemJS or RequireJS to load HTML Templates. Here is the repo for the default loader: https://github.com/aurelia/loader-default

If you would like some help figuring out what you need to do, please join us in our Gitter channel at https://gitter.im/Aurelia/Discuss

Comment: Where do I book it in @EisenbergEffect :) ?

Comment: @Ashley Grant, I do feel up to it and would like to understand more about the loader interface and whether it makes sense. Will join the Gitter, thanks Rob, Ashley.